# Como activar reactividad de componenete

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, vuex

Veran tengo un formulario de edicion del usuario en el cual se llena con los datos que usuario a editar para eso uso clone para copiar los datos del usuario que estan en el store (ademas uso un mapGetter para cuando se modifique actualice) y asi este no se modifique cuando cambio los valores en el formulario, lo que quiero es que al momento de darle click al boton cancelar use los datos que se encuentran en el store para llenar nuevamente el formulario ya sea lo que haya escrito en el, es decir digamos que en NOMBRE: RONA, y escribo en ese campo quedando NOMBRE: RONALDO, entonce al hacer click en cancel se vuelve a colocar en RONA.
Un dato importante a decir es que si asignado un valor distinto que el de `state.userSelected` entonces si se activa la reactividad y cambia el valor en el formulario

Este es mi formulario

```
<template>
  <v-flex lg10>
    <v-card class="elevation-12">
      <v-alert v-if="message"
       :value="true"
       :type="typeMessage"
      >
        {{message}}
      </v-alert>
      <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
        <v-toolbar-title>User Edit</v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container grid-list-lg>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex md5 offset-md1>
              <v-text-field prepend-icon="person"
              v-model="user.firstname" label="First Name"
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md5>
              <v-text-field
              v-model="user.lastname" label="Last Name"
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md6 offset-md1>
              <v-text-field prepend-icon="email"
              v-model="user.email" label="Email"
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md4>
              <v-text-field prepend-icon="phone" mask="(###)-##-####"
              v-model="user.phone" label="Phone"
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md5 offset-md1>
              <v-text-field prepend-icon="person"
              v-model="user.username" label="Username"
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md5 offset-1>
              <v-text-field prepend-icon="lock"
              label="Password" hint="At least 8 characters"
              :append-icon="e1 ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'"
              @click:append="() => (e1 = !e1)"
              :type="e1 ? 'password' : 'text'"
              v-model="user.password"
              counter
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn @click="resetForm">Cancel</v-btn>
        <v-spacer v-if="showList"></v-spacer>
        <v-btn v-if="showList" @click="goView('list')">Go List Users</v-btn>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn @click="updateUser" color="primary">Update Info</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-flex>
</template>

<script>

import { mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      e1: true,
      showList: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      user: state => _.cloneDeep(state.userManagement.userSelected),
    }),
    ...mapGetters({
      typeMessage: 'getTypeMessage',
      message: 'getMessage',
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    resetForm() {
      this.$store.dispatch('cancelUpdateUser', this.user.ID);
    },
    updateUser() {
      // this.$store.dispatch('updateUser', this.user);
      if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken') !== undefined && localStorage.getItem('accessToken') !== null) {
        this.$store.dispatch('updateUser', this.user)
          .then(() => {
            this.resetForm();
          })
          .catch(() => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            console.log('Error');
          });
      } else {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Login', params: { successAlert: true } });
      }
    },
    goView(item) {
      this.$store.dispatch('updateTypeMessage', 'info');
      this.$store.dispatch('updateMessage', '');
      this.$store.dispatch('openSelectedView', item);
    },
  },
  created() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken') !== undefined && localStorage.getItem('accessToken') !== null) {
      this.showList = true;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Y este es el store que maneja la mutacion

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import manejadorservicio from '@/services/manejadorservicio';

export default {
  state: {
    currentComponent: 'list',
    users: [],
    userSelected: {
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      username: '',
      password: '',
    },
    typeMessage: 'info',
    message: '',
  },
  getters: {
    getUsers(state) {
      return state.users;
    },
    getUserSelected(state) {
      return state.userSelected;
    },
    getTypeMessage(state) {
      return state.typeMessage;
    },
    getMessage(state) {
      return state.message;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    updateUsers(state, payload) {
      state.users = payload;
    },
    updateUserSelected(state, payload) {
      state.userSelected = payload;
    },
    updateCurrentComponent(state, { componentName }) {
      state.currentComponent = componentName;
    },
    updateTypeMessage(state, payload) {
      state.typeMessage = payload;
    },
    updateMessage(state, payload) {
      state.message = payload;
    },
    cancelUpdateUser(state, payload) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log('clonado: ',state.userSelected,' clon ',_.cloneDeep(state.users.filter(m => m.ID === (payload))[0]), ' id',payload);
      // state.userSelected = _.cloneDeep(state.users.filter(m => m.ID === (payload))[0]);
      state.userSelected = _.cloneDeep(state.userSelected);
    },
  },
  actions: {
    clearUpdateUser({ commit }) {
      commit('clearUpdateUser');
    },
    cancelUpdateUser({ commit }, payload) {
      commit('cancelUpdateUser', payload);
    },
    fetchUserSelected({ commit }, payload) {
      manejadorservicio.FetchUserSelected(payload.ID)
        .then((resp) => {
          commit('updateCurrentComponent', { componentName: 'edit' });
          commit('updateUserSelected', resp.body);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log('Error');
        });
    },
    fetchAllUsers({ commit }) {
      manejadorservicio.FetchAllUsers()
        .then((resp) => {
          commit('updateUsers', resp.body);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log('Error');
        });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Pero la reactividad esta siempre prendida.. lo que pasa es que vos cambiaste el valor, y ahora queres volver al original.. No reactivar reactividad.. Si vos vas y haces una mutation en el store, vas a ver que tu form va a cambiar a ese valor. Podrias hacer una mutation al valor original, o volver a pedirlo manualmente.

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por responder pero para q entiendas un poco mejor se uso lodash para poder realizar una copia (clone) del objeto y lo q se asigna en el formulario no es el objeto userSelected del store sino una copia y esa copia es lo que cambia, al final busco busco hacer una mutacion por el objeto original es decir userSelected = userSelected y lo hace pero no me presenta cambio en el formulario a cambio si uso otro usuario si se cambia el formulario ejemplo: Nombre = Rona , le escribo Ron al cancelar no cambia a Rona se queda Ron, a cambio si uso otro usuario como Juan el Nombre si cambia

Comment: por lo que vos decis, si tu form no usa el valor traido del store, entonces cualquier cambio al store no le impacta. Tu store deberia tener un get para que te devuelva lo que vos queres, y asi si seria reactivo. No suena a buena idea tomar algo del store y despues cambiarlo en tu vista.. porque de esa forma si perdiste toda la reactividad.